# ¿Cómo realizar la autenticacion OAuth 1.0 para woocommerce?

Tags: c#, wordpress, api, woocommerce, oauth

Antes de nada gracias, es la primera vez que voy a escribir, aunque si lo he usado bastantes veces.

Les pongo un poco en situación, estoy intentando usar la API REST de Wordpress Woocommerce desde una aplicación en c#.

En  wordpress he cambiado los enlaces permanentes y he creado una clave en la api rest de lectura/escritura (ck_... y cs_...).

Usando Postman y mediante la autenticación OAuth 1.0 consiguo que me devuelva los datos, en mi caso de los pedidos.

http://localhost/wordpress/wc-api/v3/orders?filter[meta]=true

En la autenticación sólo pongo la consumer_key y consumer_secret y me devuelve los datos., de hecho si miro la consola la llamada que realiza es la siguiente:

GET http://localhost/wordpress/wc-api/v3/orders?filter[meta]=true&oauth_consumer_key=ck_……&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1586951821&oauth_nonce=GKkrS5tdync&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=igKzzqzTNeSTSHRyOx4T9ucZWak=

pero no se como obtener los datos que necesito. He visto como conseguir el timestamp y el nonce en:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378232/rest-api-authentication-oauth-1-0-using-c-sharp

pero para obtener la signature he visto que necesito un token que no se como conseguirlo, en postman solo puse el consumer_key y el consumer_secret. 
Si pueden ayudarme u orientarme se lo agradecería.
Un saludo y gracias

Comment: según la [documentación](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#authentication-over-http) la forma de generar la `signatureBaseString ` ( que luego firmas ) es igual que en el ejemplo que das pero no hay que incluir `oauth_version` ni `oauth_token`. el [source del código que valida la signature](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-rest-authentication.php#L355) te puede dar un par de pistas de cómo se recrea y comparan los signatures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, he utilizado un paquete nuget de visual studio llamado Woocommerce.NET.
Creo que el proyecto en sí se puede ver en:
https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET